# When I try add insert a value into a asp.net Detailsview I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, detailsview

What do I do to fix an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" error. Which object is it referring to?
code:

```
Private Sub dvSMasterCurrentYear_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dvSMasterCurrentYear.DataBound
    Dim dv As DetailsView = New DetailsView
    If DetailsViewMode.Insert Then
        DirectCast(dv.FindControl("PlantYear"), TextBox).Text = GetYear()
    End If
End Sub
```

Get Year returns to current year, it appears in the detailsview textbox "PlantYear". I try to insert the value using the above code.

thanks for your help.

Comment: you have to allow that `FindControl` can return null/Nothing.  When/if it does that code will throw an NRE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely FindControl is not actually finding the control. It would be wise to put a check in to ensure it has actually found what you intended it to find:

```
Private Sub dvSMasterCurrentYear_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dvSMasterCurrentYear.DataBound
    Dim dv As DetailsView = New DetailsView
    If DetailsViewMode.Insert Then
        Dim ctl = dv.FindControl("PlantYear")
        If ctl IsNot Nothing Then
            DirectCast(dv.FindControl("PlantYear"), TextBox).Text = GetYear()
        Else
            Throw New Exception("Control was not found")
        End If        
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This took care of the Null Object Reference. I still can't get the value to save to the record. Here is the function I use to  GetYear:         Public Function GetYear()
        Dim thisDate As Date = Now
        Dim thisYear As String
        'thisDate = #2/12/1969#
        thisYear = Year(thisDate)
        Return thisYear
    End Function